# How can I convert and move a filed in a class which is a string containing json into a new class entry in the DB

Tags: json, orientdb

In OrientDb I have a class which contains a field which is an string , this string is a json. Can i convert it to a new class entrance and link it to the field automaticaly via command line?

Answer (score 0):

With OrientDB 1.7.9-SNAPSHOT you can do:

```
update V set emb = embedded.fromJSON('embedded') where embedded is not null
```

Where "embedded" has the json as string, and the new fromJSON() function parse it and store as "emb" field.